# Display text on same line as HTML Table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Yes <input type="radio" value="yes" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>No <input type="radio" value="no" /></td>
    </tr>
</table> Test Text
```

Normally, the text 'Test Text' will be pushed to the next line. Is it possible to keep the 'Test Text' text on the same line as the table?

Comment: People on Stack Overflow appreciate reasonably worded questions. You might want to elaborate a little bit.

Comment: I believe he wants it to appear on the same line of the table, not the line after it

Comment: I second that, it's just too ambiguous to understand what he wants.

Comment: How do you manage to make things between brackets appear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<table style="width: 250px;float: left;">
    <tr>
        <td>Yes <input type="radio" value="yes" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>No <input type="radio" value="no" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

Some text
```

Comment: Tested with a table of a row. The text is correctly aligned with the table.

Answer (score 7):

Just in case someone needs the reverse:

```
Some text <table style="display:inline-table">
    <tr>
        <td>Yes <input type="radio" value="yes" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>No <input type="radio" value="no" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Tested with a table of a row. For some reason the text is not aligned with the table, but a little lower than the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
<div style="width: 70%;float:left">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Yes <input type="radio" value="yes" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>No <input type="radio" value="no" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div style="width:30%"> Test Text</div>
</div>
```

Let me know if this works... Change the percentage to whatever fits for you

http://jsfiddle.net/ARMRh/

Comment: Even the link in jsfiddle doesn't work here. While the accepted answer does work.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this.  You might want to check for browser compatibility though.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table style="display: inline;">
        <tr>
            <td>Yes <input type="radio" value="yes" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>No <input type="radio" value="no" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>test
    </body>
</html>
```