# How to vertically align text on the right of a table to the middle of the table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, vertical-alignment

I have created an 'inline' table using this extremely useful [Stack Overflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159337/display-text-on-same-line-as-html-table), made to look like a fraction. A picture of it is put below:

[image: three over five in a table]

Now all works fine, but look at what happens when content next to it is placed in:

[image: three over five with a plus sign (not working)]

The plus sign aligns itself with the top of the table. So I was wondering, is there a way to align it to the middle of the table(near the vinculum or middle line)?

**EDIT:** Due to user requests, this is the code for my table and also the plus sign:

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: auto; float: left; margin: 2px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td style="text-align: center;padding: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">3</td></tr>
    <tr><td style="text-align: center; padding: 5px;">5</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
+
```

Also, all of the above code is placed in a p element.

Comment: @SreenathSoman what do you mean?

Comment: post the html code, which is producing the above mentioned result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you use tables? I think this is better:

HTML:

```
<span class="fraction">
    <span>5</span>
    <span>3</span>
</span>
+
<span class="fraction">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.fraction{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.fraction>span{
    display:block;
}
.fraction>span:first-child{
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/7aQUP/

**Edit:**

You can also add padding in order to increase the bar when you have fractions inside fractions:

```
.fraction>span{
    padding:0 7px;
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/7aQUP/2/

Answer (score 1):

This is aligned properly in IE8

```
<table style="width: 250px;float: left;">  
   <tr>        
 <td>3+ </td>     </tr>     <tr>       
  <td>5</td>     </tr> </table>
```

Comment: I cannot insert the plus sign in the element. It is actually outside.

Comment: Is the + sign is outside the table element?

Comment: I tried in jsfiddle while using safari, but it didn't seem to work. I wanted the plus sign down near the vinculum.

Comment: This is what your code looks like in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/think123/v5TFC/

Answer (score 0):

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: auto; float: left; margin: 2px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;padding: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; padding: 5px;">5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: auto; float: left; margin: 2px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;padding-top: 20px;">+</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>​
```

This looks to be working. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Cg9jy/1/

Comment: no I wanted the + sign to be vertically aligned along with the table so that it appears near the vinculum or line.

Comment: sorry about that, but my plus sign is just by itself, so maybe you want to change the css styles for the table?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sreenath Soman's idea, I increased the padding in the `p` element, and I used a negative `margin-top` to move the whole table upwards. If it wasn't for the padding, half the table would have disappeared. So that's what the padding was for.