# How to delete whole span element with contenteditable spans inside it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable `div`. Inside, I have put a 'fraction' span, with regards to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121011/how-to-vertically-align-text-on-the-right-of-a-table-to-the-middle-of-the-table). Here's my current code (the numbers in the spans are just dummy numbers):

```
<span style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;" contenteditable="false">
  <span style="display:block; min-width: 20px;border-bottom:1px solid black; text-align: center; outline: none;" contenteditable>6</span>
  <span style="display:block; min-width: 20px;text-align: center;outline: none;" contenteditable>7</span>
</span>
```

My problem is, when I try to delete this 'fraction' span (the outer span, and it should be deletable, as this is a Maths WYSIWYG Program), it just removes the content of the two inner contenteditable spans. When I try to delete it (obviously from outside the outer span but inside the contenteditable div), I want all three elements to get removed. I don't want the outer span still lingering.

Any solutions?

**UPDATE:** If there is no way to do this, is there a way to select that whole span element and its contents when the user presses the delete key next to the big fraction span?

Comment: Could you show what you tried? Or at least a bit of js to better understand your issue?

Comment: No it's actually simple enough - I'm trying to create a Maths WYSIWYG Program as mentioned above, and I'm stuck on the part where after a user creates a 'fraction', they have difficulty deleting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just provide the top span with an id:

```
<span id="editfraction" 
      style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;" 
      contenteditable="false">
```

and use this to delete it:

```
$('#editfraction').remove();
```

If you want to delete the span when the user presses the delete button, use ids, combined with a data attribute on the contentEditable spans.

```
<span ... data-ondeleteId="#editx" contenteditable>6</span>
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/JyzDb/) for an example

Comment: yes, but it is actually the user deleting it (sorry I most likly didn't make this clear), and they also can insert multiple fractions, so most likely this won't work.

Comment: Hi @think123: I cooked up a jsfiddle, see edited answer. Is that what you meant?

Comment: just edit one of the values in the right-bottom panel and press the delete key

Comment: +1 oh yes I see. Now just one more thing - How do I make it so when the user presses delete outside of the outer fraction span, the page automatically selects the whole outer span and including all of its contents for ease of removal?

Comment: if you don't understand what I mean, like in your example if they tried to delete the fraction without selecting it, can the code automatically select the whole fraction?

Comment: I think that's a different question, and I don't think I quite understand what you mean. You can make a document wide delete method, but what if there are multiple elements like yours? Try fiddling around with the code in the given jsfiddle (I've added an extra editable element).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15939/discussion-between-think123-and-kooiinc)

Comment: Sorry @think123, I don't have time for a chat at the moment, have to attend to my work now.