# How to select everything inside a span tag, including the span tag itself?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, html

I have a contenteditable div, in which I have a span tag, which contains some text. How do I select the span tag and all of its contents, so when the user presses backspace or delete, the span and its contents get removed?

**UPDATE:** When I say select, I mean highlight. Sorry for the inconvenience.

**UPDATE 2:** I'm thinking along the lines of 'element.outerHTML.select()'. See if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox you have the [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Selection) which allows you to do that. Combine it with the [DOM2 Range API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range-20001113/ranges.html#Level-2-Range-idl) and [you have what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/qpykF/):

```
var r = document.createRange();
r.selectNode(domElement);
var s = window.getSelection();
s.removeAllRanges();
s.addRange(r);
```

The Selection API found its way in a future standard, [HTML Editing APIs](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#selections), but it will be a while until it becomes available in a majority of browsers.

Comment: Are you sure this selects the whole element and its contents? I'm not that sure.

Comment: Yes, see the [description of the selectNode method](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range-20001113/ranges.html#Level2-Range-method-selectNode). If it doesn't, then it's a browser bug, but I doubt that such a bug would have persisted so long, given that the Range API dates back to 2000.

Comment: Is this using Prototype? If it is, can you write it using jquery, as that's the library i'm using.

Answer (score 1):

yesterday I answered [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172520/how-to-delete-whole-span-element-with-contenteditable-spans-inside-it/). I revised the jsfiddle accompanying that answer, [please recheck it](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/JyzDb/). Use `shift+delete` from within an editable span to bring up a dialog and to 'select' the current span.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var span = document.getElementById("myspan");

span.onclick = function() {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(span);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
};​
```